# Visual Studio 2013 - Source control only for one project

Tags: git, version-control, repository, visual-studio-2013

I have solution with 2 projects. Project 2 depends on dll created in project 1. But I want to have separate git repos for each project within that solution. Is it possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 currently doesn't really support this through the UI, but you should be able to set this up through the commandline.

Comment: @jessehouwing I know. I was using command line all the time. I was just hoping that I could make my work easier by using build in feature.

Comment: Maybe when you use SubModules...

Comment: You could use submodules or subtree depending on your specific needs. See the git documentation for more information.